# Discover and mount all filesystems on all drives (including LVM)

Tags: lvm, automount

I have a Live CD that I am creating that will access all physically attached disks on a machine. There is no user intervention involved and I need to find and mount all drives that can be mounted. I also need to be able to handle if the disk or disks are using LVM or not and mount each volume group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I came up with to find and mount all disks available. This script will also keep track of all failed mounts (which I needed in my situation as well, not part of the question but could be useful to others).

Here I scan all partitions in `/proc/partitions` and attempt to mount each partition I find. LVM partitions will be listed in this file as well after scanning and activating them.

```bash
# Scan for all volume groups
lvscan
# Activate all volume groups
vgchange -a y

# Get all partitions (-n+3 skips first 3 lines since they do not contain partitions)
# Also skip partitions that are loop devices which is actually the ISO cd itself
all_partitions=$(tail -n+3 /proc/partitions | awk '{print $4}' | grep -v loop)

# Array of failed mounts
declare -a failed_mounts=()

# Mount each partition to /mnt/{partition name}
for partition in ${all_partitions}; do
    mountdir=/mnt/${partition}
    mkdir -p ${mountdir}
    mount /dev/${partition} ${mountdir} &>>${INIT_LOG}
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Failed to mount ${partition}"
        rm -rf ${mountdir}
        failed_mounts+=(${partition})
    fi
done
```

This may or may not be dependent on the distro but since I am integrating this into a live CD it does not have to be distro independent.

Answer (score 0):

### Only the LVM part

Activate all volume groups first:

```
vgchange -a y
```

Then

```
lvdisplay -c | sed -e 's/  //; s/:.*//'
```

should give you a list of the activated LVM volumes.  They should be of the form `/dev/VGNAME/LVNAME`, you can now use this to create mountpoints as you wish.

Comment: Thanks but this is a somewhat incomplete answer. I also need to be able to figure out which disks are possible to mount.

Comment: edit: For instance, what other disks are there that are not necessarily using LVM that I need to mount as well?